# unsigned long * buffer

Tags: python, pointers

I'm trying to extend python with C++ to talk to an instrument. But I'm having some problems with pointers (and buffers). I'm still new to C++/C language.

In my C header file, I have a function:

```
long EXPORT read_output(long DeviceID, char* Buffer, unsigned long Length, unsigned long* BytesRead);
```

So I've created this function in my Python module:

```
static PyObject *
Py_Get_ASCII(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
  long DeviceID;
  char* Buffer;
  unsigned long* BytesRead;
  int param = PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "lz", &DeviceID, &Buffer);
  //something for BytesRead (dont' know)***
  long response = read_output(DeviceID, Buffer, strlen(Buffer), BytesRead);
  // * enter more code depending on value of response
  Py_INCREF(Py_None);
  return Py_None;
}
```

This might be dumb, but I am confused as to how I am supposed to interpret "unsigned long* BytesRead" and create a buffer for it. The header file only says that BytesRead is supposed to represent the number of bytes read, which I am assuming is what's read by the device. Everything appears to work, except when I try and incorporate "BytesRead." I'd appreciate some help on what I'm supposed to do.

Comment: Have you considered using [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html)?

Comment: There is no such language as "C++/C". Which language are you _really_ using? Then remove the other tag. Thanks.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit OK fine, if that helps. Removing my _answers as comment_, anyways you've posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any "buffer".

Traditionally you instantiate an actual `unsigned long` then pass a pointer to it:

```
unsigned long BytesRead = 0;
long response = read_output(DeviceID, Buffer, strlen(Buffer), &BytesRead);
//                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Now `BytesRead` contains the number of bytes read.

This technique is known as [*out parameters*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming)#Output_parameters), and works around the restriction that functions may only return one value.

Comment: Also is there a more elegant solution to using the
char* Buffer; ? 
I've tried instantiating it and then getting the output:
char Buffer = " "; 
long response = read_output(DeviceID, &Buffer, strlen(Buffer), &BytesRead);

But I get an error saying I can't convert char to char*...

Answer (score 0):

If read_output is to read something, it will probably return he number of bytes read in the parameter BytesRead. For that reason read_output wants a pointer to the location where it will store this number of bytes read. Then you must declare it in your calling function  Py_Get_ASCII as 'unsigned long BytesRead' and pass it to the function as '&BytesRead'.